# Join sub variables in a List

Tags: c#, string, list, class

I have my variables class with constructor

```
public class Gdf2Lines
{
    public string line { get; set; }
    public int linenumber { get; set; }
    public string columnNumber { get; set; }
    public string columnName { get; set; }

    public Gdf2Lines()
    {
        line = "";
        linenumber = -1;
        columnNumber = ""; // prefer to keep as the string read from the text source
        columnName = "";
    }

}
```

I have my class that creates of list of the above class and populates the variables within for each line from a file

```
class GDF2
{
    Gdf2Lines Data = new Gdf2Lines();

    List<Gdf2Lines> gdf2 = new List<Gdf2Lines>();

    public GDF2(string[] arrFile)
    {
        int count = 0;
        foreach (String line in arrFile)
        {
            Data.line = line;
            Data.linenumber = count;
            Data.columnNumber = GetColumnNumber(line);
            Data.columnName = GetColumnName(line);
            count++;

            gdf2.Add(Data);
        }
    }
}
```

I know a "normal" list can be joined into a string by:

```
String.Join(Environment.Newline.ToString(), List);
```

But is there an equally easy way to join one of the (sub) variables within my list, such as

```
String.Join(",", gdf2.columnName);
```

Currently I am using a for loop.

Comment: You can use LINQ: `string.Join(",", gdf2.Select(x => x.columnName))`

Comment: + Make a new `Gdf2Lines` object in the `foreach` loop and add the **new** object to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
String.Join(",", gdf2.Select(x => x.columnName));
```

This uses LINQ to extract a list of `columnName` values from the list of `Gdf2Line`.

Comment: Thank you. Too long since I C# 'ed. I must get to know Linq again.